# Use integral test to show that Gaussian Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \ dx$ converges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

There's a question in my book (it's a school-specific textbook) saying:

Use the integral test to show $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \ dx$$ (the Gaussian Integral) converges.

The integral test says if the integral converges, so does the series. But I have no idea how to represent this as a series, do I need to?

I'm not looking to evaluate it - I've read about it online - but how do I use the integral test here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** A potential problem is at infinity.

Since we know that
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to \:+\infty}\, (1+x^2)\times  e^{-x^2}=0
$$ then there exists a constant $A$ such that
$$
(1+x^2)\times  e^{-x^2}<1, \quad x\geq A,
$$ giving
$$
\int_A^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx\leq\int_A^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx<\infty
$$ but
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \ dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \ dx$$ and your initial integral is **convergent**.

Comment: you could just use the more obvious $e^{-x}>e^{-x^2}$ for $x>1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Exact! Thanks.

Comment: It just wasn't clear where you got the limit in the line starting "since you know...." I didn't see anything in the original post indicating that OP know that.

Comment: I have some doubt to imagine someone dealing with integrals like  this one not knowing that $
\lim\limits_{X \to \:+\infty}\, X\times  e^{-X}=0
$. It is rather a basic fact, in my humble opinion.

Comment: And yet it is *never* right when helping someone to tell them what they know. Saying "Since we know..." is better, because "we" is ambiguous ("We" could mean "you and I" or it could mean "we mathematicians.") If you suggest that a person knows something that he does not, it can make them feel stupid.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Edited. Thanks for this lesson!

Comment: @OlivierOloa I follow what you've done, thank you. But I don't yet see how this relates to the integral test and a series.

Comment: @JonathanWu Please, what series are you talking about? Thanks.

Comment: It says use the integral test to prove it is convergent. I think I've got something mixed up but I thought the integral test related a series and an integral - a series converges if it's improper integral is finite. I thought I would need to show something here to do with the series

Comment: @JonathanWu Ok, I understand your point. You may use the fact that the integrand is decreasing to get $$0<\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \ dx\leq \sum_0^{\infty} e^{-n^2}\leq\sum_0^{\infty} e^{-n} <\infty$$ giving the desired convergence.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2} dx = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = 2\bigg[\int_0^1 e^{-x^2} dx + \int_1^\infty e^{-x^2} dx\bigg]$$

plus $e^{-x^2} \leq e^{-x}$ for $x> 1$and $$\int_1^\infty e^{-x} dx = \color{#f05}{\frac{1}{e}}$$

Comment: How can we use the property of even function before hand.

Answer (score 2):

You have $0< e^{-x^2} \le e^{-|x|}$ if $|x|\ge 1$. This paves the way for a very simple comparison to show your integral converges.