# Does the $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{{-x}^2} \, dx$ integral converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I got this exercise as an optional challenge for students.

This integral is supposed to converge, and in fact, [the Math Stack community has already done it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187577/use-integral-test-to-show-that-gaussian-integral-int-infty-infty-e-x), but I'm looking for something more detailed, integral there aren't shown with the detail I'd expect, hence the overall understanding of the method is somewhat difficult.

I hope I don't botter the community by asking this.

Greetings and thank you.

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you cite seems pretty explicit to me.  Please indicate the steps where you would like more detail.

Comment: @saulspatz The accepted answer begins with a "since we know that" and states a limit. How can we know that's true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$$e^{-x^2}\leq \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Comment: How can you proof that?

Comment: @JesúsIsea : By proving that $e^x\geq x$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

It's often called the Gaussian integral. You can easily Google many wonderful proofs it's equal to $\sqrt{\pi}$. If all you want is a proof of convergence, use $x^2\ge |x|$ for $|x|\ge 1$, $x^2\ge 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: How can we use that fact ($x^2\ge x\ge0$) in a convergence proof?

Comment: Just prove $e^{-|x|}$ has a finite integral.

Comment: It's not difficult, not only to show this integral is convergent but to determine that it is equal to